# Serialize no flask-marshmallow com relacionamento

Tags: python, flask, serialização, sqlalchemy

Estou usando o [flask-marshmallow](https://flask-marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) para fazer o serialize no meu projeto. Junto com ele estou utilizando o  flask-sqlalchemy para o mapeamento das minhas tabelas.

Segue a estrutura:

**models/Area.py:**

```
config.database import db


class Area(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'AREA'
    
    id = db.Column('AREA_ID', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column('AREA_NOME', db.String, nullable=False)
    deleted = db.Column('AREA_DELETADO', db.Boolean, default=False)
    project_id = db.Column('PROJETO_ID', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('PROJETO.PRJ_ID'), nullable=False)

    project = db.relationship('Project', backref='project', uselist=False)
```

**models/Project.py:**

```
from config.database import db


class Project(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'PROJETO'

    id = db.Column('PROJETO_ID', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    desc = db.Column('PROJETO_DESCRICAO', db.String, nullable=False)
```

**schemas/AreaSchema.py:**

```
from config.marshmallow import ma
from ..models.Area import Area


class AreaSchema(ma.SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Area
        include_fk = True
```

**Service para serialize:**

```
def get(id):
    area = Area.query.filter_by(
        deleted=False,
        id=id
    ).first()

    if area is None:
        raise NotFound('Area not found')

    area_schema = AreaSchema()
    output = area_schema.dump(area)
    return jsonify({'data': output})
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "data": {
        "deleted": false,
        "id": 10,
        "name": "Nome da Area",
        "project_id": 1
    }
}
```

Preciso que os dados do Project apareça no output também, fiz conforme a documentação e não está aparacendo. Qual seria o problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Da documentação: https://flask-marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Da resposta dessa pergunta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44511079/flask-sqlalchemy-marshmallow-nesting

Precisa informar que há um campo Nested:

```
class CatSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'status')


class ItemSchema(ma.ModelSchema):

    class Meta:
        model = Items
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'category')

    category = ma.Nested(CatSchema)
```